# Read system Clipboard data in java

Tags: java, clipboard

I want to read data from system clipboard. I could get the copied text from clipboard using the below code. But How can get if i copied multiple files or folders.

**Code**

```
Clipboard c=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
try {
     System.out.println(c.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
} catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
}
```

The same code show exception if i have copy file lists in the clipboard.

**Exception**

```
java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException: Unicode String
```

How to get and print the copied file paths and its name from the clipboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `DataFlavor.stringFlavor` you should be using `DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor`

This will return java.util.List, containing the list of files that you've selected.
Make sure to cast it properly:

```
List fileList = (List)c.getData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for is: `c.getData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)`

Comment: Thanks whoever has +1ed me. Now can post comments too :)

Comment: I still can't upvote question/answer, need one more upvote :(